# How to search child row content

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I would like [this demo](http://datatables.net/blog/2014-10-02) to work with the filter, not removing entries whose children have the data that you are filtering for.

E.g. in the example if you filter for `5407` Airi Satou does not get deleted and maybe even the child data gets expanded.

HTML and JS

```
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<div class="slider">'+
        '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
            '<tr>'+
                '<td>Full name:</td>'+
                '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
            '</tr>'+
            '<tr>'+
                '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
                '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
            '</tr>'+
            '<tr>'+
                '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
                '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
            '</tr>'+
        '</table>'+
    '</div>';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "/examples/ajax/data/objects.txt",
        "columns": [
            {
                "class":          'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );

    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            $('div.slider', row.child()).slideUp( function () {
                row.child.hide();
                tr.removeClass('shown');
            } );
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()), 'no-padding' ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');

            $('div.slider', row.child()).slideDown();
        }
    } );
} );
```

CSS

```
td.details-control {
    background: url('/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

tr.shown td.details-control {
    background: url('/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}

div.slider {
    display: none;
}

table.dataTable tbody td.no-padding {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

In order for jQuery DataTables to search child rows you need to add data displayed in the child rows to the main table as hidden columns.

For example, you can add hidden column for `extn` data property using [`columns.visible`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.visible) option as shown below:

**JavaScript:**

```
    "columns": [
        {
            "class":          'details-control',
            "orderable":      false,
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "position" },
        { "data": "office" },
        { "data": "salary" },
        { "data": "extn", "visible": false }            
    ],
```

**HTML**:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <th>Extn.</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nnb97rh9/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: btw how to use api.myjson and how did you get the json that you used in the fiddle?

Comment: @Toskan, JSON file is available when you download DataTables, I just uploaded it to http://myjson.com

Comment: After adding        { "data": "extn", "visible": false } I am getting the error DataTables warning: table id=all_list - Requested unknown parameter 'extn' for row 0, column 8. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4